# RGB LED lit keyboard with custom color depending on focused application

Tags: gaming, keyboards

For my job I need to get used to plenty of new applications which partly make heavy usage of keyboard shortcuts. I´m not especially fast with computers and even after weeks I dont get really used to it. Some of the applications I must use dont even offer an alternative to the keyboard shortcuts like a clickable button or menu entry.

I know there a lots of fancy RGB lit gaming keyboards. I think a keyboard with customizable key colors could help me out. When I was in store they only showed me keyboards which can be configured with a few presets. This is not what I need. I need the ability to customize the colors so that specific keys are lit depending on the application which is active at the moment. When I tab into another app the color should change.

Do you know a keyboard or software which enables such functionality?

Comment: Do you have any other requirements? You just described about 90% of gaming keyboards. Do you want mech or membrane? Wired or wireless? Do you want macro keys? What's your budget in USD?

Comment: The keyboards I saw only had customizable keys only in the sense of 3 or 4 presets which you could make. I dont have any other requirements. I dont want to break the bank with this. I like decent build quality.

Answer (score 2):

The [Razer Cynosa Keyboard](https://amzn.to/38zFrBN) is a membrane, wired "gaming" keyboard. It has individually programmable backlit keys. Using the accompanying Razer Synapse 3 software,

> you can rebind buttons, assign macros, and personalize device lighting.

**Sale** on Amazon for **$44.00 USD**: [Buy Razer Cynosa](https://amzn.to/38zFrBN)

Comment: And can you program the backlit keys in a way that they are automatically changing when tabbing into an other app?

Comment: @Arjihad Yes, using the profiles feature of the Razer Synapse 3 software, you can assign your various lighting profiles so that the keyboard automatically switches to them when tabbing into other applications.